# JAIN SIP - between requests

Tags: jain-sip

How can I link two or more `RequestEvent`'s to know that it comes from the same user?

`ServerTransaction` cannot be used, as it can be more during the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Dialog links multiple requests if you opt for Dialog-stateful mode. Otherwise you can just link them yourself based on the Call-ID and tags.

Comment: How can I opt for `Dialog`-stateful mode. The `Call-ID`s for two subsequent requests are different.

Comment: If the Call-ID is different then dialog-stateful won't help you either. This is quite unusual and you should give more details about the scenario. In any case it will have to be a custom code on your side to find the relationship between requests. SIP itself doesn't define relationships outside of dialogs.

Comment: You should post the full logs and explain the scenario with messages. sipjs is capable of large number of custom scenarios.

Comment: I was actually using the URI address in the Contact header for this.